# Saving variables after reloading original js code

Tags: javascript, html, variables, local-storage

I have been trying for hours how to find a solution to my JavaScript code but I have found so many different examples but none of them seem to work with my code.

I know I want to use these variables that are currently in my code and here are the variables.

```
var isInGame = 0;  // Not playing yet

var money     = 0;  // Our cash

var North = "";

var South = "";

var East  = "";

var West  = "";

var hasArmour  = 0; // current does not own Armour

var hasWater = 0, hasSword = 0; // currently uncrowned     variable changes during game play.
```

I know I need to do something along the lines of

> loadVars -> read variable from storage -> set it to variables -> start the game

but I can't figure it out. I researched for hours before I finally gave up and just decided to ask for help.

I tried using html5 localstorage but couldn't figure it out and I was under the assumption loading vars from cookies was bad

It's using `getElementID` so it's been confusing how to save the vars during the same but reloading them when a user comes back to my website and plays again.

It's using pure JavaScript / HTML5 / CSS.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `localStorage.setItem(itemX, valueofItemX)`? Keep in mind `valueofItem` is saved as a string, and also you don't have that much space for `localstorage` Perhaps consider using Data Bases/AJAX/PHP

Comment: my code is at about 2814 lines of java script code so rewriting it all would be  difficult. i need a way to save say     var money and save the varriable each time money is added to it for example money + money = price; then the money is added client side so i'm not sure if i cant do this at all but i wanted to ask ;3

Comment: What's the specific issue? Are you getting values from the server side? If yes do you need to send them back? What issue did you have with local storage?

Comment: when the script is ran threw the browser the varriable are changed but when you leave the script ends and all of the stored varriables where only used while on the site but are reset once you come back

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use localStorage to save your values, it's as simple as

```
localStorage.setItem('money', money);
```

and later, you can retrieve it as

```
var money = localStorage.getItem('money');
```

Keep in mind that you only have 10MB of local storage space per origin to work with, and that all values will be stored as strings.

Comment: okay i took your advice but i ran into another issue but i think it will work now thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

If I were you, I would keep whole game state in some kind of an object ( or combine into an object before save ) and then just turn it into string representation / do reverse action when trying to load state.

```
let gameLogic = {
  meta: {
    inGame: false,  
  },
  directions: {
    north: '',
    east: '',
    west: '',  
  },
  character: {
    money: 0,
    armour: 0,
    water: 0,
    sword: 0,
  }
};

localStorage.setItem('gameState', JSON.stringify(gameLogic));
gameLogic = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gameState'));
```